# Icing that hardens for dog cakes

Tags: dogs, treats

I am looking to make an icing that hardens after I have frosted the doggie cake. Any ideas?

Comment: What ingredients do you make the doggie cakes out of? and what type of ingredients are you looking for the icing?

Comment: [This website](http://www.entirelypets.com/dog-frosting-recipe.html) provides a few recipes for dog treat frosting, and each post explains whether the frosting dries hard or soft.

Answer (score 2):

You can mix coconut oil with either yogurt chips or carob chips, melt it down and as it dries on top of cookies or cakes, it hardens. Ratio is one tablespoon of coconut oil per 1/2 cup of chips. You may have to wait for one layer to settle, then add a second layer on for it to be nice and thick.

I know it's a brief answer, but it's the only one I know and have used before that hardened Everytime.

I found this online along with a list of others a year or two back, and you may be able to find others that sound like something your dog likes by searching "firm or hardened icing for dogs" or "dog baking". Here's a link I found with a recent search, simply on dog icings that dry hard http://www.dogtreatkitchen.com/dog-treat-icing-that-dries-hard.html there seems to be mixed results BUT are additional links on the page with other recipes, besides the one on page1.